# How to run a command with multiple options in the heroku shell?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to debug one of my heroku containers with the following command:

`heroku run -a dashboard-container python3 manage.py runserver`

The command from above works but I need to map the contents of the heroku container to my browser and the command that might do the trick is:

`heroku run -a dashboard-container -p 3000:8888 python3 manage.py runserver`

or

`heroku run -p 3000:8888 -a dashboard-container python3 manage.py runserver`

However, heroku indicates `Illegal option -`

I looked into the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-container-run) where several options are displayed but there's no indication of how to join multiple options.

What am I missing in my heroku syntax? I am assuming Heroku is capable of handling several options in the `run` syntax but if I am wrong please correct me. Any suggestion, comment or feedback in this problem is greatly appreciated :)